# npm install --save next/Link does not work and returns an error, no path on disk 'link.js'

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, next.js

I was simply trying to create a link in my next.js app, when I tried to run it it asked me to install 'Link' but it requested for me to sign into my git account (no idea why) and on the browser I received the error you see at the bottom here.

Any ideas on what to make of it?

```
Error in C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\pages\index.js?entry
Module not found: Error: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\next\Link.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `link.js`.
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\next\Link.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `link.js`.
    at factoryCallback (C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:269:40)
    at factory (C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20)
    at applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:70:21)
    at C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:265:18
    at that.fileExistsWithCase (C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:156:15)
    at that.getFilenamesInDir (C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:97:7)
    at fs.readdir (C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:63:5)
    at C:\Users\Tali\Desktop\practice\NextJs\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:70:14
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: I don't see a screen shot here.  You should post your error as text anyway.

Comment: We need a bit more info mate. Can we see the actual error?